# Copy a label on tkinter and change the text on button click?

Tags: python, tkinter, copy, label

I have some program of this kind of type:

```
from tkinter import *

def apply_text(lbl_control):
    lbl_control['text'] = "This is some test!"

master = Tk()

lbl = Label(master)
btn = Button(master, text="apply", command=lambda: apply_text(lbl))


lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

My aim now is to copy the text of the label `lbl` itself without any ability to change it. I tried the following way to solve the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

def apply_text(lbl_control):
    lbl_control.insert(0, "This is some test!")

master = Tk()

lbl = Entry(master, state="readonly")
btn = Button(master, text="apply", command=lambda: apply_text(lbl))


lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

because of `state = "readonly"` it is not possible to change the text insert of `lbl` anymore. For that reason nothing happens if I click on the button `apply`. How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to do that simple first change the `state` of entry to `normal`, Then insert the text, and then change the `state` back to `readonly`.

```py
from tkinter import *

def apply_text(lbl_control):
    lbl_control['state'] = 'normal'
    lbl_control.delete(0,'end')
    lbl_control.insert(0, "This is some test!")
    lbl_control['state'] = 'readonly'

master = Tk()

lbl = Entry(master, state="readonly")
btn = Button(master, text="apply", command=lambda: apply_text(lbl))


lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```

There is another way to do this using `textvariable`.
Code:**(Suggested)**

```py
from tkinter import *

def apply_text(lbl_control):
    eText.set("This is some test.")

master = Tk()

eText = StringVar()
lbl = Entry(master, state="readonly",textvariable=eText)
btn = Button(master, text="apply", command=lambda: apply_text(lbl))


lbl.pack()
btn.pack()

mainloop()
```